# Get the path from Uri in Android Kitkat throws Illegal Argument exception

Tags: android, video, cursor, android-contentresolver, mediastore

I'm trying to get the path from uri. it works in devices below kitkat. I googled and found that I need to get the document Id and then query it with the gallery items. And it works. But I'm facing problem with videos. When i select the video from Videos section, it works. But When I select it from Gallery, my app crashes, giving Illegal Argument exception- Not a document type. I know why it's happening. It is because I'm looking for a document type of video in Gallery section. But how to prevent this. So that I can select videos from both Gallery & Videos Section.

Here is my code:

```
public static String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri,String type) {
    if(isKitkatBelow()) {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }else{

        String docId= DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(contentUri);
        String id=  docId.split(":")[1];
        if(type== TYPE_IMAGE){
            String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            String whereClause=MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";
            Cursor cursor=context.getContentResolver().query(getUri(type),proj,whereClause,new String[]{id},null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }else{
            String[] proj = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
            String whereClause=MediaStore.Video.Media._ID + "=?";
            Cursor cursor=context.getContentResolver().query(getUri(type),proj,whereClause,new String[]{id},null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }



    }
}
```

This is happening because I'm trying to search a file of type MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA in Gallery. But for devices below kitkat, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA gets the video uri, from the gallery too without causing any crash. Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use for getting absolute path from the Uri of selected file because of differences in both KitKat(API 19) and below Kitkat in android to achieve this using following code,

```
public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                        + split[1];
            }

            // TODO handle non-primary volumes
        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"),
                    Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { split[1] };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection,
                    selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
 * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
 * 
 * @param context
 *            The context.
 * @param uri
 *            The Uri to query.
 * @param selection
 *            (Optional) Filter used in the query.
 * @param selectionArgs
 *            (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
 * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
 */
public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri,
        String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {

    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = { column };

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection,
                selection, selectionArgs, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * @param uri
 *            The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
 */
public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri
            .getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri
 *            The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
 */
public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri
            .getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri
 *            The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
 */
public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri
            .getAuthority());
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. But i have one query. if there are any other apps and if user selects from them, then it crashes right..

Comment: User selects from them means?

Comment: No it worked..there was some problem with my code..It's working now