# Android uploading ANY file to Server

Tags: android

I'm working on an application where user can select any file from SD Card and upload it to the server. User can also click image from camera and upload the image. This works fine but when I try to select any other file from File Explorer It just doesn't work.

Code to let User select Any File:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); 
    intent.setType("file/*"); 
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    try {
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), GET_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please install any File Manager to complete the task.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Code to get the result from Activity:

```
if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(data.getData().toString());
            File myfile=new File(uri.getPath());
            sendSelectedFileURI(myfile.getAbsolutePath());
            Log.d("patho",uri.getPath());
            Log.d("path",myfile.getAbsolutePath());
        } else if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_CANCELED) {


        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
```

Then I'm simply creating file and adding it as FileBody to the HttpEntity as follow:

```
File sourceFile=new File(filepath);
entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(sourceFile));
```

In some devices I get correct path and file gets uploaded to the server where in some devices it throws File not found exception. It throws error on the line where I'm creating FileBody.

So what I want is user can select any type of file from the SD card and select it to upload on server.

Comment: experiment with a 'chooser' . It will return a Uri -> file which may more reliably be used to open file -> new FileBody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After referring to the following link I solved the issue.

[Get the path from Uri in Android Kitkat throws Illegal Argument exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27497520/get-the-path-from-uri-in-android-kitkat-throws-illegal-argument-exception)

Basically we need to check for DocumentURI on KitKat and above Builds.